# IF Statement to check if the link_title == then display this code

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, links

I am working on a section which uses ACF and each service has it owns colour (for background of an icon etc).
This has been setup in Theme Options and I am trying to run an IF statement which checks to see if the repeater link equals a certain value, to then echo some code.

The below code is working in the sense that it does echo the link's title.

```
<?php 
$link = get_sub_field('link');
if( $link ): 
    $link_url = $link['url'];
    $link_title = $link['title'];
    $link_target = $link['target'] ? $link['target'] : '_self';
    ?>
<?php //echo esc_html( $link_title ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have so far tried multiple different IF statements yet none seem to work, currently I am sat with the following code:

```
<?php if($link_title == "Royalty Audit") { ?>
  <div class="services-icon p-20 rounded-full" style="background-color:<?php the_field('royalty_audit_colour', 'options'); ?>">
    <x-image image-id="{{ $imageId }}" image-size="full" class="inset-0 object-cover object-center" />
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction?

Note:
The above is for a Service repeater which displays the services left to right, 6 in width. I have an icon, title, link (with link text) for each repeater.

I have another section at the top of each Service page, which checks to see if the sub fields title (just an ACF field name) equals a certain value. This code works perfectly.

```
<?php if(get_sub_field('title') == "Royalty Audit") { ?>
```

Comment: what is the value of `$link_title` is you print it out directly? How are you verifying that it contains what you thought it contained? Note that ACF and other 3rd party plugins are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope, if any ACF knowledge is necessary to answer this question then it must be closed as offtopic. Note that the ACF tags descrition states it is off topic and where to go to ask ACF questions